# How do I query by only part of a composite key in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Let's say, I have `User`s writing reviews of `Product`s.

User and Product are separate entities with their own ids.

`Review` is an entity with a composite id composed of `userId` and `productId`.

I have created a table `review` in DynamoDB with both `userId` and `productId` as HASH keys.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name review \
  --attribute-definitions \
      AttributeName=user_id,AttributeType=S \
      AttributeName=product_id,AttributeType=S \
  --key-schema \
      AttributeName=user_id,KeyType=HASH \
      AttributeName=product_id,KeyType=RANGE \
  --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

Thus making `userId`+`productId` the composite key.

The review data object is held against that key.

Querying for a review by user and product is fine.

But how do I query for all reviews by a user or all reviews for a product?

With a single parameter, e.g. if I do a query by single key conditional expression with just `"#user_id = :userId"` or just  `"#product_id = :productId"`

I get an error of the form

```
Query condition missed key schema element: user_id
```

or

```
Query condition missed key schema element: product_id
```

Comment: Can you show the full query that's giving you the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have created a table review in DynamoDB with both userId and productId as HASH keys.

You've created a composite primary key for your review table, which consists of a Partition Key of `userId` and a and a Sort Key of 'productId' .  You did **not** create two HASH keys.

Logically, your review table will look something like this (I've made up some data for illustration purposes):

[image: review table]

This table structure makes it easy to fetch reviews by user.  Here's an example of a query for all reviews of `USER#ABC`

```
ddbClient.query(
  "TableName": "<YOUR TABLE NAME>",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "#userId = :userId",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":userId": {
      "S": "USER#ABC"
    }
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#userId": "userId"
  }
)
```

This will return a collection of items reviewed by USER#ABC.

DynamoDB will *not* allow you to fetch items by *only* specifying the Sort Key (e.g. productId).  You **always** need to provide the Partition Key. So how do you get a list of Users who have reviewed a given product?

If you want to search for all Users that have reviewed a single Product, you could introduce a global secondary index that swaps the Partition Key and Sort Key of your table.  This pattern is known as an [inverted index](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/design-a-database-for-a-mobile-app-with-dynamodb/5/#:%7E:text=An%20inverted%20index%20is%20a,primary%20key%20for%20your%20table.).  Using my example from above, an inverted index would look like this:

[image: global secondary index by productid]

This would allow you to fetch users by productId:

```
ddbclient.query(
{
  "TableName": "<YOUR TABLE NAME>",
  "IndexName": "reviews_by_product_index",
  "KeyConditionExpression": "#productId = :productId",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":productId": {
      "S": "PRODUCT#456"
    }
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#productId": "productId"
  }
}
)
```

This query would return a collection of two items representing reviews for `PRODUCT#456`.

When working with a composite primary key, you *can* search based on conditions of the *sort key* as long as you also specify the partition key.  That's a mouthful, but it allows you to perform queries like (in pseudocode)

> query where partition key = "USER#ABC" and sort key begins_with "PRODUCT"

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks.

Comment: it doesnt work for me:  WHERE business_id#type_id#partner_id=435634652#3#69992528