# Query GSI in DynamoDb with a substring of the key (begins_with)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Let's take the best practices for sort keys official documentation of DynamoDb as an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html

Imagine we have a table like the documentation mentions, where our sort key is a composite that looks like:

`[country]#[region]#[city]#[neighborhood]`

For example, something like this:

| Partition Key (Employee Name) | Sort Key | Other columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Antonio | Spain#Madrid#Getafe#Whatever | ... |
| Maria | Spain#Andalucia#Sevilla#Whatever2 | ... |
| Mike | Spain#Madrid#Alcorcon#Whatever | ... |

And I'd like to get all the records from a specific country + region, so we have a partial sort key:

`[country]#[region]` like `Spain#Madrid` to get `Antonio` and `Mike`.

I know it's not possible to query by sort key directly, so I created a GSI with the inverted index (like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64141405)

| Partition Key | Sort Key | Other columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain#Madrid#Getafe#Whatever | Antonio | ... |
| Spain#Andalucia#Sevilla#Whatever2 | Maria | ... |
| Spain#Madrid#Alcorcon#Whatever | Mike | ... |

But it still looks like it's not possible to query using the `begins_with` operator.

```cs
var request = new QueryRequest
{
    IndexName = "GSI_Name",
    KeyConditionExpression = "begins_with(SortKey, :v_SortKey)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
        {":v_SortKey", new AttributeValue { S = sortKey }},
    },
};
```

My question is: is there any way to achieve this without using the `Scan` operation which is not ideal? Or any suggestion to change my table definition to achieve this? I've been trying to think of ways of restructuring the table to accomplish this behavior, but I'm not fluent enough with DynamoDB.

Comment: Worth adding the error message that you see when issuing that query so that future searches find your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the country as the PK and the rest as the SK. That spreads the data nicely across partitions while also enabling your access pattern.

Comment: In case it's unclear, I think you are suggesting a GSI query for pk == `Spain` and sk begins_with `Madrid#`, which can be extended to query for country/region/city etc.

Comment: Right! It's also possible to just use a single PK value in the GSI, but then you don't have as much partition spread as you'd like.